# laravel custom request changes sql table

Tags: laravel, validation, request

I made a custom request for validation

```
    class StoreModule extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|unique:posts|max:50',
            'period' => 'required|integer|min:1',
            'block' => 'required|integer|min:1', 
            'study_points' => 'required|integer|min:1', 
            'my_teacher_id' => 'required',
            'tags' => 'required', 
            'coordinator_id' => 'required', 
            'category' => 'required|max:50', 
            'deadline' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

However when I apply this class to my controller

```
public function store(StoreModule $request)
{
    $module = Module::create($request->all());
    $module->tags()->sync($request->tags);

    return redirect()->route('admin.index');
}
```

I suddenly get an SQL-error

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydatabase.posts' doesn't exist
```

When i replace the StoreModule extends FormRequest class with a regular Request eveything works just fine and the object is stored in my mydatabase.modules table.

Why is laravel suddenly looking for mydatabase.posts table? I already tried declaring 
`public $table = 'modules';`
in my Module model class

Any tips or help is appreciated. Please ask if I need to provide more details

Comment: are you using another connection of the database? if yes, you should add the connection name in validation rules.
e.g. `'name' => 'required|unique:mydatabase.posts|max:50',` -> this rule is accessing your posts table

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this and I resolved with a middleware. Could not be the best approach but solved the problem. Since I use different DB connection in the project, this middleware comes in hand :)

In your code, you defined $table with public, but should be protected like:

```
protected $table = 'table name';
```

Take this piece of code, its the middleware I wrote.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $database)
{
    // check witch database connection to use
    switch ($database) {
        case 'lamimail':
            // Set the User Database Connection
            DB::setDefaultConnection('lamimail');
            // Reconnect
            DB::reconnect();
            break;
        case 'lamiapps':
            // Set the User Database Connection
            DB::setDefaultConnection('lamiapps');
            // Reconnect
            DB::reconnect();
            break;
        default:
            // default action
            abort(403, 'Não está autorizado a aceder ao recurso solicitado.');
            break;
    }
    // next request...
    return $next($request);
}
```

Call it in function or __construct:

```
$this->middleware('SetDatabaseConnection:lamimail');
```

Remember, the case condition in switch() are the connection name to DB located in config/database.php.

Hope it helps.